# what does ' t ' denote in copy constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor, copy-constructor

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class tester {
public:
int a;
tester( int x ) {
    a = x;
}

tester( tester &t ) {
    cout << t.a;
}
};

int main() {
 tester t(10);
 tester t_1(t);
}

output : 10
```

In definition of copy constructor what does `t` refer to ? From main when i passed `t` in the argument of `t_1`,it's address got stored in the form `&t` in the copy constructor. What does `t.a` mean ?

Comment: how much c++ do you know?

Comment: You're getting confused with addresses and references.

Comment: I'm going to recommend finding a [good introductory C++ book](http://tinyurl.com/so-cxxbooks). This is very a basic C++ question, and any beginner book will surely clear up any similar doubts you might have.

Comment: @ Donotalo what was the purpose of this comment ?

Comment: @steve: assessing someone's knowledge level helps provide better explanations. I'm going to assume that was the point of Donotalo's comment.

Comment: @steve: whoever wants to learn c++ (or in general any language) should grab a good enough book and start reading it chapter by chapter. there is no shortcut way to learn things and i always discourage such practice. from your post it is clear that you haven't tried enough on your own. from my judgement you don't deserve answers for questions which are found in any book. i'm sorry if my comment hurts you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In copy constructor `t` is an reference to the object of the type `tester`.

Copy constructor is a **copying function**.
It creates a copy of an object of an class, So it takes the object of that class an parameter. This copy constructor is called to create temporary copies of object during call by value in function calls etc.

**Why this parameter is passed by Reference?**
The reason that the parameter is passed as an reference in copy constructor is to avoid the recurssive calling of copy constructor if it was passed by value.(since copy constructor itself is the function which creates that temporary object)

**What does `t.a` mean ?**
Since `t` is an reference to the object of the type `tester`. `t.a` is the member `a` insidethe class `tester` for the object `t` being passed to the copy constructor.

Answer (score 5):

It's a reference to the existing object which is being copied to construct the new one. The copy constructor is expected to read the relevant fields from `t` as needed.

In your example, you probably want to copy the `a` field like this:

```
tester( tester &t ) {
   cout << t.a;
   a = t.a;
}
```

Comment: Isn't it that only objects can refer to the data members using dot operator ?

Comment: No... if `a` were declared `private`, then only code in the `tester` class would be able to access it. But the copy constructor is part of the class, so it can access the members of other objects of the same class. And anyway, `a` is `public` in your example.

Comment: @steve: Do you know what a reference is in C++? If not, read about it. Regarding your example: `tester &t` is a reference in your copy constructor. A reference is similar to a pointer but you don't access members with `->` but with a `.`.